# How to set PowerShell variables to True or False

Tags: powershell

PowerShell logic question:

```
$a = 1
$b = 2
if ($a = $b) {
    $ans = $true
}
else {
    $ans = $false
}
Write-Host $ans


Output:
True
```

Can someone explain to me why this evaluates as true? Is it because I assign $ans to true first? Also, could someone show me how to get this to evaluate the way I think it should?

Comment: You can omit `if` at all using `$ans = ($a -eq $b)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're doing an assignment `$a = $b`, the assignment succeeds and that returns true because b was true, so the first case will always evaluate to true at the moment, instead use a comparison: `$a -eq $b`.

[More detailed information on comparisons in powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: No such thing as `==` notation in powershell, equivalent of `===` would be `($a -eq $b) -and ($a -is $b)`. `-is` is the type comparison operator.

Comment: In fact, the `$a = $b` assignment **does not** return _true_ but `$b`. For instance, `if ($a = 0) {…} else {…}` would reach the `else` branch due to some automatic type conversions. Please note valid construct `$var1 = $var2 = 'some value of any type here'`.

Comment: That was what I meant, but I see how you could read that differently. Thanks for pointing out, updated.